# How to recover a gas assembly file that was accidentally overwritten

Tags: linux

This is an open ended question, but essentially, I wrote a program in x86 assembly and compiled it to an executable. I accidentally ran the command `cp program program.s` while attempting to move files around, and I overwrote my asm source code with the binary. I am trying to recover the source file in its original form

I want to note that I also am working in a wsl linux environment and using vscode, and so maybe it's possible to directly recover the file through other ways, like I don't know if vscode saves some kind of cache in case this happens, and please let me know if this train of thought is viable, but I figure my best bet is to disassemble the binary.

I know I can do `objdump -d program` and get the assembly, but it is not in gas form, and there are a lot of other information in this output, so it would be a lot of manual labor to recover the original .s file with the output of this command. Are there any other ways to better disassemble an exe into the original assembly file?

Thanks

Comment: Is restoring the latest backup an option?

Comment: wdym by backup? I didn't do any backups of my drive or anything like that

Comment: @Dyskord he means that any critical data should be backed up to avoid data loss. In case of code there exist solutions like git, which make it really easy to keep a backup and a version history.

Comment: Yeah, usually I would use git. Unfortunately, this was just an afternoon silly project, so I didn't think to use any kind of version control